# Random response to message discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I’m developing a basic discord.js moderation bot. As one of the functions I need the bot to respond to a message with one of many pre programmed responses.

Eg.
Message = ‘Hello’
Response = ‘Hey’ or ‘Hi’ or ‘Goodday’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work for you, It selects a random value from an array with your messages in it.

```js
// your messages should go into this array
const messages = ["message one", "message two", "message three", "message four"]

const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];

console.log(randomMessage)
```